# Boostrap 4 dropdown run down animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for the way to make my boostrap 4 dropdown has animation like this when hovered.

My boostrap's dropdown:

```
https://codepen.io/longpham10/pen/rNBEEgz
```

The hover dropdown animation I want for my boostrap's dropdown:

```
https://codepen.io/longpham10/pen/QWLeLMB
```

Edit: I got soulution here:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
  transition:.8s;
  top:-1100%;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu{
  top: 100%;
}
#dropdown-animation { 
// add id="dropdown-animation" next toclass="dropdown-menu"
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css and using your current code, maybe this:

```
    /* reset css*/
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}



/*********** navbar css *************/

.navbar {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5px 6px 2px rgba(60,64,67,.15);
}

.nav-link{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    width: 14.5rem !important;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    z-index: 3 !important;
    opacity 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-item a {
    color: #677282 !important;
    font-family: 'roboto medium';
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu{
  transform: translateY(-2%);
  opacity 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* roat carret icon on hover */
.nav-item:hover .nav-link .fa-caret-down {
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.nav-item .fa-caret-down {
    color: #ff6f00;
}

.dropdown-item {
    white-space: normal !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown-item .menu-item-name {
    color: #425066;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.dropdown-item .menu-item-description {
    font-family: 'roboto regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #737d8c;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-item:hover .menu-item-name {
    color: #ff6f00;
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i want but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>  
$('ul.navbar-nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
</script>
```

If you need an explanation let me know. Otherwise mark the question as done.